# Button to stop a stopwatch not working correctly!

Tags: arduino-uno, button

I'm trying to implement a stopwatch with an LCD display, and I'm supposed to be using the `attachInterrupt` command to catch the button press. The clock runs perfectly, but the button input isn't caught or acted upon at all.

In `void setup()`, I have set it up this way: `attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(buttonPin), buttonInterrupt, RISING);`.

And the buttonInterrupt function only does `start = !start`, so in a sense just flipping the start variable.

This is the updated version of the code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
int buttonPin = 7; 
volatile int buttonState; 
int lastButtonState;
long sec; 
long startTime;  

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Push the button!");
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(buttonPin),buttonInterrupt,HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin); 
  if(buttonState == LOW){
    startTime = millis(); 
  }
  
  while(buttonState == HIGH){
    long time = millis();
    long z = (time - startTime); 
    sec = (z/1000);
    long ms = z%1000; 
    lcd.setCursor(0,1); 
    lcd.print(sec); 
    lcd.print(".");
    lcd.print(ms);
    lcd.setCursor(8,1); 
    lcd.print("Secs");
    
    if(buttonState == LOW){
      break;   
    }
  }
}

void buttonInterrupt() {
  if(buttonState == LOW){
    buttonState = HIGH; 
  }else{
    buttonState = LOW; 
  }
}
```

The loop function works as far as time counting is concerned, but doesn't work to stop the time with the button. Any help is appreciated, I'm extremely new to Arduino (literally started yesterday). My circuit looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHHy5.png

If there is any other way to print the numbers other than printString, more than happy to hear them!

Thanks!

Comment: In your wiring diagram the button has a pullup resistor? Are you sure, that this resistor is not connected to ground instead? Also I cannot see anything for debouncing the button. You won't get good results without debouncing

Comment: @chrisl you are right, it is supposed to be connected to GND, but fixing that doesn't solve my issue either! And unfortunately I do not know what debouncing means! Will have to look that up now. Thanks!

Comment: is variable start `volatile`?

Comment: @Juraj, no it was not. But even I switch to volatile, it does not seem to help.

Comment: You need to set `msStart` to the current `millis()` value after the while loop. A better way would be to make the code non-blocking like in the BlinkWithoutDelay example. Also don't expect the stopwatch to be too precise because the code in your while loop will take some time and therefore `sec=sec+1;` will not be executed *exactly* every 1000 ms

Comment: Another tip: be consistent with the datatype of `start`. If it is a boolean, you better use `true\false`. If it is an integer, you better don't use the NOT-operator (`!`). If `start` becomes `1` at one point, `start=!start` will make it toggle between 1 and 254, which probably is not what you intended

Comment: You better post the whole, **compilable** code, so things like the datatype of `start` are clear to people reading the question.

Comment: @Sim Son thanks for your answer! I have tried a different way of flipping the start variable, now that you mentioned boolean, it's clear to me my way didn't make any sense to flip 0 to 1. That being said, this solution did not fix the issue, and I'm not sure how to set `msAtStart` to `millis()` as this causes the stopwatch to tick to 0.1s and then tick back to 0.0. Thanks for your help! I have posted the whole, compilable code in my question body now.

Comment: Does it start when you press the button, though?

Comment: @ocrdu nope, it does not! if i set `start = 0;` it doesn't start at all, and if i put it to 1, the timer starts as soon as I start the program.

Comment: Nothing at all from the button then. With the answer you got you from Edgar Bonet you should be able to get it to work. Get that button wired up properly first, and see what happens. Or I could post working code, but where's the fun in that?

Comment: @ocrdu I wired it up correctly and tried a different method now. The button input works now - at the click of the button, the timer starts, but a second click doesn't stop it. So now the problem is with debouncing maybe or just my interrupt function. I still don't quite get debouncing so will have to read a bit about that, but atleast the button and the clock are working sort of OK.

Comment: @ocrdu now I just cannot figure out how to get an "updated" button state that will kill the while loop and let the output stay there. that is what the Interrupt is supposed to do, but the state switch in the interrupt funct from LOW to HIGH / HIGH to LOW doesn't seem to reach the while loop. Quite confused...

Comment: Loop() already loops. Lose the while. If buttonState == HIGH, calculate and display time passed. Otherwise, do nothing.

Comment: Oh, I see you changed the code. Don't set buttonState in the loop(), leave that to the interrupt. You can worry about resetting the startTime later. And don't use INPUT-PULLUP unless the switch connects the input pin to LOW.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues here. First and foremost, your button is wired
incorrectly. If you connect one end of the button to +5V, then the other
end should have a pushdown to GND, like here:

[image: Wiring of a button]

(Image from the [Arduino Button example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/Button)).

The second issue is the lack of debouncing. You should ignore the rising
edges you sense for a few milliseconds after you record one.

The third issue is the timekeeping. As explained by Sim Son, your
seconds will not be very accurate. It's better to just count the
milliseconds elapsed since the button press, and then break the count
into full seconds and remaining milliseconds.

Comment: Hi @edgar bonet - thanks so much for the answer! I have fixed a couple of things you talked about here. the stopwatch now starts upon the press of a button, but a second button press doesn't stop it. I assume that's because of the interrupt function, but I don't see where exactly the problem is. Any help is appreciated! Thanks. I have posted the updated code in the main body of the question. The debouncing I have not quite understood and haven't implemented yet.

Comment: @Raighley: The code now is a mess, and I can't quite understand what it is trying to do. If you use `INPUT_PULLUP`, you don't need a pulldown, and the button is active when `LOW`. `attachInterrupt()` doesn't support a `HIGH` mode. There is no point in using both `digitalRead()` and `attachInterrupt()`. `buttonState` seems to serve two unrelated purposes. `lastButtonState` is never used... I suggest to restart from scratch: forget about interrupts, read about “button bounce”, and use a debouncing library.